# Crystal Report using XML

Tags: xml, asp-classic, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 9.0 (Can't upgrade due to some constraints)
My application is in classic ASP using ADO

My application will retrieve XML data from a Web Service exposed by a service provider and i need to generate a Report using this XML data.

Is there any way to do so?
Thx in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have the Crystal Report read the xml file directly. When you create the report, use the choose XML from the available datasource connections and proved the information relating to the web service in the XML connect setup. I believe that you should be able to point it directly to your webservice if you choose "Use Web Service Data Source" and pass in the necessary information. I'm am looking at this using Crystal 11, but I believe that this was available in Crystal 9. If not I am pretty sure that there is another XML datasource connection that you can use. You may have to create the report using a local xml file similar to what you would expect back from your webservice and then set the datasource of the report at runtime to the xml from the webservice, but I am pretty sure you should be able to get this working. Hope this has been somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is possible because crystal reports expects dataSet as datasource for report just transform you xml data in such a way that you can load it in dataset you are ready
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: Thx Lordon for reply. 
my application is in ASP & ADO hence we use recordset. There is no in-built method to convert XML to ADO Recordset.

Dataset isavailable ADO.net and i dont think ADO.NET can be used in classic ASP pages.

Comment: In that case it is my mistake but still is there no way to create recordset at run time an just read the xml node by node and fill it in the record set ?